# Angularjs controller fails to load http data from cachefactory service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

Newbie to angular, using service I'm trying to load cachefactory and using the cache from controller.

Here is service methods

```
codesApp.service('CodeFilterService',function($filter, $http, CacheService,$log){
this.getByCodeType = function (codeTypeValue, codeName) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(CacheService.get('Codes'))) {
        loadCodes();
    }
    return  $filter('filter')(CacheService.get('Codes'), {codetype: codeTypeValue, name: '!' + codeName});
};

this.getAllCodes = function () {
    $log.info("getAllCodes");
    if (angular.isUndefined(CacheService.get('Codes'))) {
        $log.info("Loading fresh getAllCodes");
        this.loadCodes();
    }
    return  CacheService.get('Codes');
};

this.loadCodes = function () {
    $http.get("./rest/codes").then(function (response) {
        $log.info("Codes Size" +response.data.length );
        CacheService.put('Codes', response.data);
    });
    };
});

codesApp.factory('CacheService',function($cacheFactory){
     return $cacheFactory('super-cache');
 });
```

Controller Code :

```
codesApp.controller('CodeCreateController',function($scope,$state,
 Code,CodeFilterService,$log){

  ... 
$scope.codeDropdownList = CodeFilterService.getAllCodes();
   $log.info("codeDropdownList = " + angular.isUndefined($scope.codeDropdownList))    ;

});
```

Here angular.isUndefined($scope.codeDropdownList)) returns true which means data not getting loaded. Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Problem is retty simple... ajax is asynchronous so you can't call `loadcodes()` and immediately return to controller. Might want to use a resolve in router to load the cache before controller runs

Comment: @charlietfl thanks,  can you provide a answer or psedocode

Answer (score 0):

You may use promise inject **$q**

```
codesApp.service('CodeFilterService', function ($filter, $http, CacheService, $log, $q) {

    this.getByCodeType = function (codeTypeValue, codeName) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(CacheService.get('Codes'))) {
            loadCodes();
        }
        return $filter('filter')(CacheService.get('Codes'), {
            codetype: codeTypeValue,
            name: '!' + codeName
        });
    };

    this.getAllCodes = function () {
        $log.info("getAllCodes");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (angular.isUndefined(CacheService.get('Codes'))) {
            $log.info("Loading fresh getAllCodes");
            this.loadCodes().then(function (result) {
                $log.error('getAllCodes success');
                var cachedCodes = CacheService.get('Codes');
                deferred.resolve(cachedCodes);
            }, function (reason) {
                $log.error('getAllCodes error: ' + reason);
                deferred.reject();
            });
        } else {
            var cachedCodes = CacheService.get('Codes');
            deferred.resolve(cachedCodes);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.loadCodes = function () {
        $log.info("loadCodes");
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("./rest/codes").then(function (response) {
            $log.error('loadCodes success');
            $log.info("Codes Size" + response.data.length);
            CacheService.put('Codes', response.data);
            deferred.resolve();
        }, function (reason) {
            $log.error('loadCodes error: ' + reason);
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});




codesApp.controller('CodeCreateController', function ($scope, $state,
    Code, CodeFilterService, $log) {

    ...
    CodeFilterService.getAllCodes().then(function (result) {
        $log.info('result: ' + result);
        $scope.codeDropdownList = result;
        $log.info("codeDropdownList = " + angular.isUndefined($scope.codeDropdownList))
    }, function (reason) {
        $log.error('error: ' + reason);
    });

});
```